# How to change page orientation in VCL FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Embarcadero version of FastReport and I need to change the orientation of some subreport pages at runtime (mostly because of pictures). Based on [Programmer's manual](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/FR4.6.ProgrammerManual-en.pdf) it should be easy, but I can't figure out how or when it is possible. I tried to change all pages in these two events, but without success. I'm not sure if it works at all in this version or I'm missing something.

`TfrxReport.OnBeforePaint`

```
procedure TForm1.frxReportBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxReportComponent);
begin
  if Assigned(Sender.Page) then
    TfrxReportPage(Sender.Page).Orientation := TPrinterOrientation.poLandscape;
end;
```

`TfrxReport.OnPrintPage`

```
procedure TForm1.frxReportPrintPage(Page: TfrxReportPage; CopyNo: Integer);
begin
  TfrxReportPage(Page).Orientation := TPrinterOrientation.poLandscape;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TfrxReportPage(frxReport1.FindObject('Page1')).Orientation := TPrinterOrientation.poLandscape;
frxReport1.ShowReport;
```

Comment: Is `Orientation` property accessible?

Comment: This  will change the orientation of all pages, not just some, also it doesn't work for subreport pages.